# Is this performance usual for an SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance

Please see the benchmark below:

HD Tune Pro: Crucial_CT512MX100SSD1 Information

```
Firmware version : MU01
Serial number    :         14420D871481
Capacity         : 512.1 gB (476.9 GB)
Buffer size      : n/a
Sector size      : 512 bytes
Standard         : SATA 3 (6.0 Gb/s)
Supported mode   : UDMA Mode 6
Current mode     : UDMA Mode 6
Avergae speed    : 4069 MB/s
Rotation speed   : 0 RPM (SSD)

S.M.A.R.T                    : yes
48-bit Address               : yes
Read Look-Ahead              : yes
Write Cache                  : yes
Host Protected Area          : yes
Device Configuration Overlay : yes
Firmware Upgradable          : yes
Automatic Acoustic Management: no
Power Management             : yes
Advanced Power Management    : yes
Interface Power Management   : no
Power-up in Standby          : no
Security Mode                : yes
SCT Tables                   : yes
Native Command Queuing (NCQ) : yes
Trim                         : yes

Volume        : System Reserved 
Capacity      : 349 MB
Free          : 90 MB
Usage         : 74%
File system   : NTFS
Serial        : 2669-6089
Alignment     : 2 MB

Volume        : (C:)
Capacity      : 487583 MB
Free          : 364608 MB
Usage         : 25%
File system   : NTFS
Serial        : E86C-270D
Alignment     : 1 MB

Volume        : 
Capacity      : 449 MB
Free          : 129 MB
Usage         : 71%
File system   : NTFS
Serial        : E6FB-5143
Alignment     : 2 MB
```

[image]

Comment: Could be typical if your OS doesn't support TRIM and you have written to a lot of the drive. What OS?

Comment: Or if (like me) you attached the drive to a controller without TRIM.

Comment: Even without TRIM the write would only be reduced, not the read. That drive should be a lot faster. Benchmark it on a bootable OS first to rule out software.

Comment: Looks like classic SATA-300 speeds. Also potential write bottleneck from lack of cache, or just crappy SSD.

Comment: is your question answered?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your motherboard only [supports SATA 3Gb/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_2.0_.283_Gbit.2Fs.2C_300_MB.2Fs.29) and so the max transfer rate is about 250MB/s.

Comment: How did you determine his motherboard only supports SATA II?

Comment: @Ramhound he sues a SSD which supports 6Gb/s, but the 250MB/s in the benchmark are the typical values for using it on a SATA 3Gb/s port